# Empty PostGIS geometry displaying correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

On a table, with pgadmin (III) I see just emptiness in the geometry column of a table, while the layer is displaying properly in QGIS (2.14). Any idea on why and how to display the geometry in pgadmin ?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://postgis.net/2013/10/05/tip_pgAdmin_shows_no_data/

Comment: Indeed, I didn't look properly. Thanks